# Mostrar MenuBar al cargar el programa

Tags: python, menú, gtk

En este ejemplo de pantalla con menús, cuando ejecuto el código, de primeras, no aparece el Menú en la parte superior (en la barra de título).

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk


# gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true
class MenuExampleWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Aloha")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        # Layout
        layout = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(layout)

        # Main container that we will stick inside our layout
        main_menu_bar = Gtk.MenuBar()

        # Drop down menu
        file_menu = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("File")

        # File menu items
        file_new = Gtk.MenuItem("New")
        file_open = Gtk.MenuItem("Open")
        file_exit = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")

        # File button has dropdown
        file_menu_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu)

        # Add menu items
        file_menu.append(file_new)
        file_menu.append(file_open)
        file_menu.append(Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem())
        file_menu.append(file_exit)

        # Add to main menu bar
        main_menu_bar.append(file_menu_dropdown)

        layout.pack_start(main_menu_bar, True, True, 0)


window = MenuExampleWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Solamente, es visible si se maximiza la ventana.

¿Por qué? ¿Habría que hacer algo más para que se muestre el menú sea cuál sea el tamaño de la pantalla?

¿Cómo sería con el menú dentro de la ventana y no en la barra de título? ¿Un ejemplo?

Usado Python 2.7 - GTK 3.0

Gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin hacer ningún cambio al código que proporcionas, el menu está dentro la ventana y se muestra invariablemente ocupando todo el espacio (debido a que está anidado en un Gtk.Box, que, valga la redundancia, ocupa toda la ventana).

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial, es preferible utilizar un Gtk.Grid a un Gtk.Box (o a los ya obseletos Gtk.VBox o Gtk.HBox):

> If you don’t need first-child or last-child styling and want your code to be future-proof, the recommendation is to switch to Gtk.Grid instead of nested boxes. For more information about migrating to Gtk.Grid, see Migrating from other containers to GtkGrid.

Fuente: [PyGObject API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/VBox.html#class-details)

En ese entendido, reemplazando tu contenedor principal por un Grid, el menu se muestra en la parte superior y no ocupa todo el espacio de la ventana. Aquí el código completo:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk


# gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true
class MenuExampleWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Aloha")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        # Layout
        layout = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(layout)

        # Main container that we will stick inside our layout
        main_menu_bar = Gtk.MenuBar()

        # Drop down menu
        file_menu = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("File")

        # File menu items
        file_new = Gtk.MenuItem("New")
        file_open = Gtk.MenuItem("Open")
        file_exit = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")

        # File button has dropdown
        file_menu_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu)

        # Add menu items
        file_menu.append(file_new)
        file_menu.append(file_open)
        file_menu.append(Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem())
        file_menu.append(file_exit)

        # Add to main menu bar
        main_menu_bar.append(file_menu_dropdown)

        layout.attach(main_menu_bar, 0, 0, 1, 1)


window = MenuExampleWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación. Si bien, como no veía como arreglarlo antes de tu comentario, me volví al Tkinter.
No obstante, me acabo de dar cuenta, por mi falta de costumbre con el entorno Linux (Ubuntu, con el que estoy ahora, concretamente), que los menús no aparecen en la barra de título de un programa abierto hasta que no pasas el cursor por encima. Por lo que, al final, fallo mío de apreciación, pues hasta con el código que yo puse, también, funciona. No obstante, por tu aportación sobre la recomendación de la documentación oficial, usaré el Grid() ... :)